# Not Able To HIVE databases in Databricks Community Edition

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

I have been using Databricks Edition for many years now, and suddenly I'm no longer able to view HIVE databases. I'm getting the following message when I select Data
[image]
I normally see my HIVE database here. Has there been a massive change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad @Patterson, it was not meant to be an answer...I am also dealing with this issue... But if you want to see your hive database(s), I would recommend you to enable DBFS by following these steps (see image below):

1. Go to the admin console.
2. Click the Workspace Settings tab.
3. In the Advanced section, click the DBFS File Browser toggle.
4. Click Confirm.

Once you do this refresh page and then you can access your file directory "DBFS". Under `/user/hive/warehouse/` you will find your default database and other databases you might have created... However, the database(s) under "Database Tables" are still not showing, for me at least.

I would recommend you to use these two statements to get more information about your schemas/databases:

```
%sql

describe detail <schema>.<table_name>
```

and

```
%sql

describe history <schema>.<table_name>
```

I hope you can find your hive's databases.

[image]

Comment: oh, @Susy84. Thanks for this. I will check this out. I thought I would have to use a live Azure Databricks Service to see the tables.

Comment: Oh. @Susy84, you answer was referring to the Community Edition, correct?

Comment: @Patterson, yes, just like what you are using, right?... By the way, the command

<code>
%sql

describe history <schema>.<table_name>
</code>
only works if your table is a delta table, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having similar issue (I am using Databricks Community Edition).

Before I was able to see the schema of the table, but now I only get an error for database.

I also tried to create a new database (successfully)

```
%sql

create database if not exists test
```

and a new table

```
%sql

create table if not exists users (
  user_id int,
  first_name string,
  last_name string,
  age int
)
```

but the new database/schema did not show under "Database Tables".

BUT they are there --> /user/hive/warehouse/test.db/users

[image: database error - cluster does not exist]

I was expecting something similar (image below), instead I only see an error message (image above).

[image]

Comment: Hi @susy84 thanks reaching out. That isn't the answer I was hoping to read.

Comment: This does not look like an answer. Only a “me too”.